# Azure SQL DB creation is throwing and exception

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I am trying to use azure SDK for Ruby to create Azure SQL server and SQL DB.

I am getting deserialization error while running the code. Though its creating the SQL server, I can see and even add database to it manually in portal. Please help.

```
require 'fog/azurerm'
require 'azure_mgmt_sql'
fog_sql_service = Fog::Sql::AzureRM.new(
  tenant_id:        'tenant_id',
  client_id:        'client_id',
  client_secret:    'client_secret',
  subscription_id:  'subscription _id',
  environment:      'AzureCloud'         )
server_data = {:resource_group = "group_name", :name = "server_name", 
:location = "location", :version = "12.0",  :administrator_login = 
"username", :administrator_login_password = "password"}
fog_sql_service.sql_servers.create(server_data)

Error message :
"message": "Error occurred in deserializing the response",
```

Comment: Please check out the AzureSupport twitter account for updates, as there is currently an outage situation which is likely the cause of your issue. Unfortunately not something resolvable here on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

You're possibly hitting a temporary issue in Azure. The [status page](http://status.azure.com) has a warning about ARM functionality being compromised.

Comment: Please just post a comment rather than an answer, and vote to close as off-topic non-reproducible), since there are many of these questions popping up, none of them resolvable here.